# Crackling sound when recording chrome tab

Tags: sound, google-chrome, pulseaudio, alsa, audio-recording

I want to record the video playing on a chrome tab. I use Ubuntu on a remote server and [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/screen-recorder/hniebljpgcogalllopnjokppmgbhaden?hl=en) extension for recording, everything is OK, except the sound. The sound is really scratchy. I don't know what the cause of this problem is. Can anyone help me please?